# what is the problem with this photo and how can i fix it?

Tags: troubleshooting, digital, nikon-d3100

[image: weddingcake]

We had a wrong camera setting on alot of pics. Is there any software to clean this up and make it clearer?

Comment: What problems do you think there is? What did you expect this to look like? What "wrong camera setting" did you have, and why do you think it was wrong?

Comment: It is not the camera settings. You need to understand thoose setings. :)

Comment: Was the camera set to some sort of 'art' setting?

Comment: This photograph looks great to me. I bet you could print it at about 80cm × 1m and sell hundreds of copies to a hotel chain.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, that photo is *much* too far gone for any software to be able to clean it up. One of the big advantages of digital over film is the ability to instantly review photos - get in the habit of using it.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you wanted a crisp picture of the flower, there are two basic problems:

Out of focus.  That really should be obvious.

Very grainy.

If this is from film, then you are blowing up a tiny area of the picture much bigger than the film resolution can support.  Don't do that.  You can't infinitely enlarge pictures without this kind of artifact.

If this is digital, then extreme high ISO was probably used.  Again, don't do that if you don't want this effect.  ISO isn't something you can magically increase without trading off with other things, like noise.

Comment: The "nikon-d3100" tag strongly implies digital :-)

Comment: Sadly I have seen a number of beginners leaving iso set to maximum setting to avoid blurry pictures in dim light. I assume they were told to do so in a dark indoor setting etc but not told to switch it back afterward.

Comment: The grain might come from trying to "sharpen" the image in software, with the maximum possible sharpening value. That of course did not improve the image, which was to much out of focus and therefore much to blurry to be improved by any software.